# Different solution configurations in VS2010

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, configuration

In `VS2010` , what is the difference between the solution configurations `DLL Release` and `DLL Universal Release`?

Answer (score 0):

By Default there is only two build Configuration in VS2010. "Debug" and "Release". But you can create new build configuration for the project using Configuration Manager in build Menu.
After creating a new build configuration you can specify specific steps to take when you build for this configuration.
For example if you build for USA or French you might like to copy resource from different place. Then you can specify the condition is copy something similar to

> Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='YourNewConfiguration|Win32'"

You can learn more from here [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kkz9kefa.aspx)

Hope this helps